# Click method not working with Cucumber Phantomjs

Tags: jquery, css, phantomjs, cucumber, capybara

Recently i saw 1 wired issue, for a specific CSS, .click method is not working with phantomJS webdriver. It works fine using chrome. I am using below code to click on it by using SITEPRISM .

```
@page = someclass.new
@page.wait_for_fld_element_rows(30)
@page.fld_element_rows.first.click
```

I saw it can click always in chrome and other drivers but not phantomjs. I am using below config for phantomjs:

```
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :phantomjs,     
desired_capabilities: { 'phantomjs.cli.args' => ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes']
```

Comment: What error does it give?  What version of phantomjs?

Comment: You didn't respond to what version of phantomjs you're using, but I'm going to guess 1.9.x which doesn't support a lot of things modern browsers do.  Try updating to phantomjs 2.1.x

Comment: Right -- 1.9.8 is ancient, and doesn't support Function.prototype.bind which a lot of todays JS frameworks depend on.  You can polyfill that in 1.9.x but it's really a much better idea to update to 2.1.x which natively supports it and many other missing features from the 1.9.x branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's 2 thing 1st you can try:

```
1st) You can upgrade to phantomjs 2.1.1 (latest) as this is more stable version.
```

or,

```
2nd) Not-clicking Issue might happenned because of the ajax req. You can use retry with in rescue block and try to click again which may solve this issue.
```

Answer (score 2):

PhantomJS 1.9.x is missing a lot of things modern JS frameworks depend on.  The usual cause of JS behavior not happening with PhantomJS, when it works in other browsers, is the lack of Function.prototype.bind .  You can polyfill that, but it's really a much better idea to just upgrade your PhantomJS to >= 2.1.x which is more stable and much closer to a modern browser than the 1.9.x releases.